# What is the name of this iron cross maneuver?

Tags: terminology, gymnastics

I was once shown a video of a male gymnast's routine on rings. He began from a still hang and pulled, slowly, with straight arms, into an iron cross and after maybe a brief pause continued the pull into a support. It appeared so slow, smooth, and controlled that the audience audibly gasped. My question has two parts: 1) how would you describe this maneuver concisely and 2) does anyone know the name of the gymnast and the video in question?

Further recollections: it was a gymnastics championship, not the olympics. I think it was at a national or maybe world level. It may have been Yuri van Gelder, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

For 1), using reference from [FIG MAG 2017 Code of Points](http://www.fig-gymnastics.com/publicdir/rules/files/mag/CoP_MAG_2017-2020_ICI-e.pdf) (PDF download), the closest one I could find was number 64 in Part 3, Rings skills section (page 87), which was

> Vertical pull up with straight arms to cross or L-cross

From my experience as a gymnast, it **could** be concisely called

> Vertical Pull up with straight arms to cross or L-cross momentarily, then lift to support

For 2), it could be possibly Yuri Van Gelder.

This is from what User28415 said but searching on Youtube gives me an idea that it could be one of Yuri's own new skills on the still rings.